# How can i change the name in admin magento?

Tags: admin, magento-1.9

[image]

I want to change the name in the admin magento,i'm trying but not ok

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Database search the table- "admin_user" here you can add Admin Username and Password manually by clicking Insert link or you can add by MySQL query- UPDATE admin_user SET password = MD5('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE username = 'ADMINUSERNAME'; . If you forgot the Database name, find from here- /app/etc/local.xml and open the code then search DB here.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to run this Query on your database:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
   VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');
```

This Query will ON the admin path hint.
After this refresh your customer page and check the specific file for titles. Open the file and change the names.